# How to insert a Column in excel VBA without pasting content from clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

1) I copy a content (value=143) from Sheet1

2) I go to Sheet2

3) I insert a new column in range("B1")

4) excel fills the entire new column with 143. And I don't want that. I want it to be a new, empty column.

I know I can get away with application.cutcopymode but when i walk the macro using F8 it doesnt work.

So I need a suggestion on how to deal with it.

I've seen a comment on a forum to insert the column first before copying, but I hate to disrupt the order of my algorithm so I'm looking for a better way to do this.

Sheet1:

```
123
141
142
143
144
145
146
147
148
149
150
151
152
153
154
155
156
157
158
159
160
```

Sheet2:

```
wda    awd
awd    daw
adw    daw
awd    wda
daw    wda
daw    awd
wda    afw
wda    weg
awd    weg
afw    w
weg    rq
weg    qrq
w      qefqw
rq     e
qrq    he
qefqw  rgw
e      rq
he     3qg
rgw    q3
rq     tq
3qg    ga
```

and the macro:

```
Sub testing()

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A4").Copy

Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
Range("b1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A4").Copy
```

`Range("A4")` refers to the Range of the sheet where your macro is stored in, not necessarily `Sheet1`.

Don't use Activate unless you really want to activate the sheet. Do this instead:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Copy

With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")
    .EntireColumn.Insert
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
```

Comment: opss the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

use `Value` property of `Range` object to paste range contents only

```
Sub testing()

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(2)).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Notice I used `Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(2)).Value = ...` to limit the value pasting to column B cells whose adjacent columns are filled with values

If you *really* need the *entire* column to be filled then just use `.Columns(2).Value = ...`

Comment: Hi, sorry I made a big mistake in the question. You may remove your final line in your answer. Another note: I do not wish to insert the column before copy. I want to COPY the value before INSERT then column, as per my question

Comment: if you WANT to COPY then you USE the CLIPBOARD.